# pyomo documentation with function signatures

Tags: documentation, pyomo

Where do I find documentation of pyomo functions and their arguments?
For example, what arguments does the `solve` method take? By looking at many examples, I have seen `tee` and `logfile` being used, but it must be documented somewhere?
Python's `inspect.signature` does not help, since it returns just `<Signature (*args, **kwds)>`.

And is there a difference between solvers' and solverManagers' `solve` methods, apart from the latter requiring(?) an `opt` parameter for the solver? (And, for that matter, is there any documentation for `SolverManagerFactory`, apart from it being used in on example (for parallel solve using pyro)?)

Also, where is documentation of the return object of `solve`? It seems to contain some useful information, but I cannot find it documented anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

A couple options options which I hope help:

1) a great (but sadly paid) book, chapter 5 covers the solve command: https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319588193
The authors of the book are active on this (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pyomo-forum) google group, they might be willing to share pages 83-86

2) a pdf version of the some documentation (check page 254 and on maybe?)
edit: link to doc https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pyomo/latest/pyomo.pdf

Comment: Thanks, I have not realized that I need to check solver interfaces (esp. since I do not have any of the three mentioned in the documentation).
It still does not say what the output type is, though...